# Using Sum on a Count Row in SQL

Tags: sql, count, sum

I have this code which when run should return a count of the total number of Taxis Hotels and Foods:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN [TaxiHotelFood] LIKE '%Taxi%' THEN 1 END) AS "Taxis",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN [TaxiHotelFood] LIKE '%Hotel%' THEN 1 END) AS "Hotel",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN [TaxiHotelFood] LIKE '%Taxi%' THEN 1 END) AS "Food"
    FROM [CSART].[dbo].[tblPatAdmission]
    WHERE (TaxiHotelFood != '' AND TaxiHotelFood IS NOT NULL)
    GROUP BY TaxiHotelFood
```

Instead what it returns is this:

```
Taxis   Hotel   Food
0         2      0
1         1      1
```

It does not add the counts unless the contents of the field are identical. Is there a simple way to fix this?

Comment: Can you supply sample data and expected results?  I don't see anything wrong with your query.  When you say `add the counts`, do you mean you only want a single row as the result (1, 3, 1)?  If so, drop the `group by`...

Comment: Wow it really should not have taken me over an hour to figure that out. Thanks, it's working now.

Comment: Did you notice the second '%Taxi%' should be '%Food%'?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
COUNT(CASE WHEN [TaxiHotelFood] LIKE '%Taxi%' THEN 1 END) AS "Taxis",
COUNT(CASE WHEN [TaxiHotelFood] LIKE '%Hotel%' THEN 1 END) AS "Hotel",
COUNT(CASE WHEN [TaxiHotelFood] LIKE '%Taxi%' THEN 1 END) AS "Food"
FROM [CSART].[dbo].[tblPatAdmission]
WHERE (TaxiHotelFood != '' AND TaxiHotelFood IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY TaxiHotelFood
UNION
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN [TaxiHotelFood] LIKE '%Taxi%' THEN 1 END) AS "Taxis",
SUM(CASE WHEN [TaxiHotelFood] LIKE '%Hotel%' THEN 1 END) AS "Hotel",
SUM(CASE WHEN [TaxiHotelFood] LIKE '%Taxi%' THEN 1 END) AS "Food"
FROM [CSART].[dbo].[tblPatAdmission]
WHERE (TaxiHotelFood != '' AND TaxiHotelFood IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY TaxiHotelFood
```